# Do I loose æmber after plaing Full Moon, then Chota Harzi?

Tags: keyforge

I've got no æmber and play a [Full Moon](https://aember-forge.com/card/full-moon). Then I play [Chota Harzi](https://aember-forge.com/card/chota-hazri). What is my æmber count after that and why? Zero or one?

It is obvious that without Full Moon being played I do not lose any æmber: there is no any. But with the Full Moon it is not clear what happens earlier: losing via the Chota Hazri or gaining via the Full Moon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The active player (presumably you) chooses the order.** The result is likely that you choose to end up with 1 æmber.

The Full Moon effect trigger and Chota's play trigger both happen when you play the card, at the same time. As such, the active player chooses the order they resolve in. Unless you're somehow doing this on your opponent's turn, you'll get to choose which comes first, and thus whether or not you end up with the æmber.

From [the rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/77/38/7738ee75-43b7-48dd-b846-72c173607d72/keyforge_rulebook_v13-compressed.pdf), page 9:

> **ACTIVE PLAYER**
>
> The active player is the player taking the current turn. The active player makes all necessary decisions for all card abilities or timing conflicts that need to resolve during their turn.